# RDF-raptor-parser

Tags: ruby, rdf, redland

I am trying to parse the rdf file but
I am getting error while executing following  code in ubuntu

```
RDF::Reader.open("http://datagraph.org/jhacker/foaf.rdf") do |reader|
  reader.each_statement do |statement|
    puts statement.inspect
  end
end
```

as

```
LoadError: Could not open library 'libraptor': libraptor: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory. Could not open library 'libraptor.so': libraptor.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I installed all the required gems:

```
rdf
rdf-raptor
ffi
rdf-json
rdf-trix
```

Please help me how to rectify this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you visit http://rdf.rubyforge.org/raptor/ and use the contact info mentioned there such as the mailing list.  The error is because the C shared library `libraptor.so` cannot be found by ruby, so it must have been installed in a non-standard place.  I am the author of Raptor but I do not know how `rdf-raptor` installed Raptor.

Comment: thanks for your replay,I got the answer from following url:        http://www.semanticoverflow.com/questions/2989/rdf-raptor-parser